# searching value with blank space and replace

Tags: javascript, search, replace

I have '      'value in my XML page I want to search and replace All it with '1234',

How it can be done?

Comment: str.replace('old value', '1234')

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
var str="aaa bbb ccc";
var out=str.replace(/ /g,"1234");  // result: "aaa1234bbb1234ccc"
```